# How to assign a single System Verilog Interface to an array of Interfaces

Tags: system-verilog

I am building an AXI arbiter (axiIxc) where it has Master and Slave ports that are arrays of the AXI interface.  I then instantiate this in myModule which has a register interface that is an Interface that I defined with the AXI signals.  My issue is that I get a compiler error because regIf is a single Interface and mPort on the AXI arbiter is an array of Interfaces of size [0:0].  Is there any way to cast the single interface to an array?  The other way works fine...i.e. the sPort is an array and I can specify which element I want to connect to a sub-module.

```
module myModule
(
  myAxiIfType.slave regIf  // registers
);

myAxiIfType regIxcSPort [0:3];

axiIxc #(1,4)  // MPort Quantity, SPort Quantity
  regAxiIxcInst (
    .mPort(regIf),
    .sPort(regIxcSPort)
  );
```

Comment: Instead of array of interface, can you make a single interface with array of ports in it?

Answer (score 0):

No. Interfaces are not the best construct for everything.